# Sum all item prices and multiplication them to them pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, shopping-cart

I have a problem to solve here, I need to calculate total price of cart.

I add multiple products to my cart. They have prices and quantities in pivot.
Something like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": "1",
"status": "closed",
"total_price": "100",
"created_at": "2017-07-22 06:06:17",
"updated_at": "2017-07-22 08:02:04",
"skues": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "مربعی ۵x2",
        "description": "مربعی ۵x2، مربعی ۵x2 است.",
        "sku_card_theme": "#2222",
        "visible": "hidden",
        "price": "50",
        "category_id": "2",
        "created_at": "2017-07-22 06:50:02",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-22 07:16:33",
        "pivot": {
            "cart_id": "1",
            "sku_id": "1",
            "feature": "{\"size\": \"big\",\"quantity\": 2}",
            "image_path": "images/users5e51d08006fed056b19db7d041d5688f.jpeg",
            "id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "مربعی ۵x2",
        "description": "مربعی ۵x2، مربعی ۵x2 است.",
        "sku_card_theme": "#2222",
        "visible": "hidden",
        "price": "50",
        "category_id": "2",
        "created_at": "2017-07-22 06:50:02",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-22 07:16:33",
        "pivot": {
            "cart_id": "1",
            "sku_id": "1",
            "feature": "{\"size\": \"big\",\"quantity\": 2}",
            "image_path": "images/users/416e9f70dee50547866e9e89696d16e3.jpeg",
            "id": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "تقویم دیواری",
        "description": "سشیشیش",
        "sku_card_theme": "#2222",
        "visible": "hidden",
        "price": "25",
        "category_id": "3",
        "created_at": "2017-07-22 07:56:45",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-22 07:56:45",
        "pivot": {
            "cart_id": "1",
            "sku_id": "3",
            "feature": "{\"size\": \"big\",\"quantity\": 2}",
            "image_path": "images/users/273c1f5e3324815a82060931f30ead97.jpeg",
            "id": 3
        }
    },

]
```

I want to sum all skues prices here and multiply them by their pivot quantity, I tried some methods like `foreach`, laravel collection `each` and other approaches...

But I have got no answer.

my code sample:

```
$skues->each(function ($item) {
    $quantity = json_decode($item->pivot->feature)->quantity;
    $price    = $item->price;
});
$total_price = $quantity * $price;
```

It has an error, telling me that `$quantity` and `$price` are undefined variables.

and this is my foreach method:

```
foreach ($cart->skues as $skue) {
    $quantity    = json_decode($skue->pivot->feature)->quantity;
    $total_price = $skue->price * $quantity;
}
$cart->update([
    'total_price' => $total_price,
]);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you echo var_dump($item->pivot) and tell us what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it finally:

```
public function total($cart) {
        $cart->update([
                          'total_price' => NULL,
                      ]);
        $cart->skues->each(function ($item) {
            $user        = auth()->user();
            $quantity    = json_decode($item->pivot->feature)->quantity;
            $price       = $item->price;
            $total_price = $price * $quantity;
            $user->cart->update([
                                    'total_price' => $total_price + $user->cart->total_price,
                                ]);
        });
    }
```

Comment: maybe not best solution but it works! anyone knows better answer please